# Can't access service in AKS

Tags: azure-aks, azure-container-registry

I've created an ACR and AKS, and pushed a container to the ACR.

I then applied the following yaml file to AKS:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: readit-cart
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: readit-cart
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: readit-cart
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: readit-cart
        image: memicourseregistry.azurecr.io/cart:v2
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "128Mi"
            cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5005
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: readit-cart
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 5005
  selector:
    app: readit-cart
```

I can run the container locally on port 5005 and it runs just fine.

In Azure portal, in the AKS resources view, I can see the service and the pod, they are both running (green).

And yet, when I try to access the public IP of the service, I get a "This site can't be reached" error.

What am I missing?

Comment: try setting it to port 80 (not 443)?

Comment: How do you run the image locally?

Answer (score 0):

OK, it looks like the problem was that the pod run on port 80, and not 5005, even though the container run locally on 5005. Strange...

I'll look further into it.